# How can I import a set of generic personal makefiles into my go project using Dep, avoiding submodules?

Tags: git, go, git-submodules, dep

I'm trying to clean out submodules from my Golang project. Submodules tagged at certain commits really complicates project setup and initialization. I'm looking for a way to import this non go project (not package) of makefiles to avoid submodule imports.

I'm using `Dep` in my project as a package manager and thought the `[required]` element would allow me to pull in external files. As it [states](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/Gopkg.toml.html):

> "Use this for: linters, generators, and other development tools that are needed by your project, aren't imported by your project (directly or transitively), if you don't want to put them in your GOPATH, and/or you want to lock the version."

Is this kind of import even possible to do?

Comment: What are you using makefiles for?

Comment: I REALLY don't want to use them. But a developer I work with enjoys them quite much. This would've been an intermediary step to getting rid of makefiles. I figured I'd help phase out the submodules first then ultimately the makefiles.